# Relativistic Kinematics Problem

Tags: homework-and-exercises, special-relativity, kinematics

> A and B travel at $4c/5$ and $3c/5$ along the x-axis with respect to the ground. How fast should C travel( C is between A and B) that she sees both A and B approach with the same speed?

I tried approaching this problem by letting $x_a$ and $x_b$ be the x co-ordinates of A and B in the ground frame, and $x_a'$ and $x_b'$ be the x co-ordinates in the frame of C. Then assuming C is moving with velocity v, with respect to the ground, we can write the Lorentz transformation

$$x_a =\gamma(x_a'+vt')$$ where $\gamma = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-{v^2}/{c^2})}}$ and another equation for B. Then differentiating w.r.t $t$

$$\frac{d}{dt}x_a = \gamma\left(\frac{d}{dt}x_a' + v\frac{dt'}{dt}\right)$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}x_a = \gamma\left(\frac{dx_a'}{dt'}\frac{dt'}{dt} + v\frac{dt'}{dt}\right)$$

$$\frac{d}{dt}x_a = \gamma\left(v_a' + v\right)\frac{d}{dt}t'$$

We get a similar equation for B

$$\frac{d}{dt}x_b = \gamma\left(v_b' + v\right)\frac{d}{dt}t'$$

My point was to use $v_a' = -v_b' $ to solve for $v$

So $$t' = \gamma\left(t-\frac{vx_a}{c^2}\right)$$

$$\frac{dt'}{dt} = \gamma\left(1-\frac{v}{c^2}\frac{d}{dt}x_a\right)$$

Substituting this back,

$$\frac{dx_a}{dt} = \gamma^2(v_a' + v)\left(1-\frac{v}{c^2}\frac{dx_a}{dt}\right)$$

and similarly

$$\frac{dx_b}{dt} = \gamma^2(v_b' + v)\left(1-\frac{v}{c^2}\frac{dx_b}{dt}\right)$$

Putting $dx_a/dt = 4c/5$ and $dx_b/dt = 3c/5$ and eliminating $v_a' = -v_b'$

$$\frac{\frac{1}{\gamma^2}\left(\frac{4c}{5}\right)}{1- \frac{v}{c^2}\left(\frac{4c}{5}\right)}-v=-\left(\frac{\frac{1}{\gamma^2}\left(\frac{3c}{5}\right)}{1- \frac{v}{c^2}\left(\frac{3c}{5}\right)}-v\right)$$

which reduces to

$$\frac{4}{5-4\lambda}+ \frac{3}{5-3\lambda} = 2\lambda(1-\lambda^2)$$ with $\lambda = v/c$   but this equations has no solutions between $0$ and $1$ so clearly I have gone wrong.

I'd like to know where I have gone wrong and if this line of reasoning can be made to work, and if not, what other way can I approach this problem.

Comment: Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It'll take some time to go through your reasoning to find the error.

(I'll admit that I am not fond of manipulating differential expressions... since I feel I am manipulating terms whose meanings are often unclear to me.)

For now, I will offer an "other way" to approach the problem.

I will offer a fast **geometrical solution** *which suggests that formulating
similar problems geometrically in Minkowski spacetime may yield a quick and more easily interpretable solution*. Of course, this takes practice to develop.

Given $v_A=4/5$ and $v_B=3/5$... we seek the "center of velocity" $v_C$ (so that $|v_{AC}|=|v_{BC}|$).

- **Using rapidities** (the Minkowski-angle) $\theta$, where $v=\tanh\theta$ and $\gamma=\frac{1}{\sqrt{1-v^2}}=\cosh\theta$, your problem is equivalent to finding the 4-velocity of the angle bisector between those 4-velocities.

  So, $\theta_A=\rm arctanh(v_A)=\rm arctanh(4/5)$ 
  and $\theta_B=\rm arctanh(v_B)=\rm arctanh(3/5)$.
  The **angle-bisector is half of the sum** $\theta_C=\frac{1}{2}(\theta_A+\theta_B)$.

   Thus, the velocity of C you seek is
  $$\begin{align*}
  v_C
  &=\tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}(\theta_A+\theta_B)\right)\\
  &=\tanh\left(\frac{1}{2}(\rm arctanh(4/5)+arctanh(3/5))\right)\\
  &=5/7
  \end{align*}
  $$
  from plugging the sectond-to-the-last expression into WolframAlpha.

  The relative-velocities with respect to C are then
   
  $v_{AC}=\tanh(\theta_A-\theta_C)=\tanh(\rm arctanh(4/5)-arctanh(5/7))=1/5$ and
  $v_{BC}=\tanh(\theta_B-\theta_C)=\tanh(\rm arctanh(3/5)-arctanh(5/7))=-1/5$.


  By the way,
   
  $v_{AB}=\tanh(\theta_A-\theta_B)=\tanh(\rm arctanh(4/5)-arctanh(3/5))=5/13$
  which is equivalent to the relative-velocity formula: $v_{AB}=\frac{v_{AC}-v_{BC}}{1-v_{AC}v_{BC}}$.
- **Using the Bondi k-calculus**, where $k=\sqrt{\frac{1+v}{1-v}}=\exp\theta$ (and the reverse relation: $v=\frac{k^2-1}{k^2+1}=\tanh\theta$),
  we get $v_C$ from $$k_C=\sqrt{k_A k_B}.$$
  Since $k_A=3$ and $k_B=2$, we have $k_C=\sqrt{k_A k_B}=\sqrt{6}$.
  Thus, $v_C=\frac{(\sqrt 6)^2-1}{(\sqrt 6)^2+1}=5/7$.

added in edit:

- **Using a tedious brute force algebraic solution using the relative-velocity formula**,
  solve for $v_C$ in
  $$\frac{v_A-v_C}{1-v_A v_C}=-\frac{v_B-v_C}{1-v_B v_C}.$$
  After some algebra, you get a quadratic equation in $v_c$:
  $$ 0= v_C^2 + \left(-2\frac{1+v_Av_B}{v_A+v_B}\right)v_C+1$$
  with two roots that are reciprocals of each other (since in the quadratic formula $0=Ax^2+Bx+C$, the product of roots is $C/A$... and here that ratio is equal to 1). So, the root that is less than 1 is the physically acceptable solution.
  The quadratic formula yields:
  $$v_C=\frac{(1+v_Av_B)\pm\sqrt{(1-v_A^2)(1-v_B^2)}}{v_A+v_B}.$$
  Since $v_A>0$ and $v_B>0$, evaluate (from $\pm$) the "$-$"-root to get $5/7$.
  *There is probably a geometric interpretation of this quadratic equation.*
  edit #2: Here is an interpretation for the result from its quadratic formula: 
  $$\begin{align*}
  v_C
  &=\frac{1+v_Av_B}{v_A v_B} \pm \frac{1}{\gamma_A \gamma_B(v_A+v_B)}\\
  &=\frac{1}{\tanh(\theta_A+\theta_B)} \pm \frac{1}{\cosh\theta_A \cosh\theta_B(\tanh \theta_A+\tanh\theta_B)}\\
  &=\frac{1}{\tanh(\theta_A+\theta_B)} \pm \frac{1}{\cosh\theta_B\sinh \theta_A+\cosh\theta_A\sinh\theta_B}\\
  &=\frac{\cosh(\theta_A+\theta_B)}{\sinh(\theta_A+\theta_B)} \pm \frac{1}{\sinh(\theta_A+\theta_B)}\\
  &=\frac{\cosh(\theta_A+\theta_B)\pm 1}{\sinh(\theta_A+\theta_B)},\\
  \end{align*}$$
  where $$\tanh\left(\frac{(\theta_A+\theta_B)}{2}\right)\equiv\frac{\cosh(\theta_A+\theta_B)- 1}{\sinh(\theta_A+\theta_B)}
  $$ is the hyperbolic half-angle formula for $\tanh()$--which references the angle-bisector.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach would be to Lorentz transform the momentum-energy 4-vector, reduced to a single momentum component.  If we assign equal masses to the objects, then if we get equal energies (and opposite momenta) in C's reference frame, then we will have equal and opposite velocities:
$$\pmatrix{E_C \\ p_C c}=\pmatrix{\gamma &-\gamma\beta \\ -\gamma\beta &\gamma}\pmatrix{E_{(A\ or\ B)} \\ p_{(A\ or\ B)}c}$$

where $\beta$ and $\gamma$ are the factors for C with reference to "the ground". Equating the two energies we get
$$\gamma\left(E_A-\beta p_Ac\right)=\gamma\left(E_B-\beta p_Bc\right).$$
Using $\beta_A=4/5$, then $E_A=5/3mc^2$ and $p_Ac=4/3mc^2.$

Using $\beta_B=3/5$, then $E_B=5/4mc^2$ and $p_Bc=3/4mc^2.$

With these values we get $$mc^2(5/3-4/3\beta)=mc^2(5/4-3/4\beta). $$
Solving this, we get $\beta=5/7$.

Plugging this back in for the momenta of $A$ and $B$ relative to $C$ we find they are equal and opposite.